# How do you query a ravendb index containing dates using Lucene?

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I am using the http api to query ravendb (so a LINQ query is not the solution to my question).
My Product document looks like this:

```
{
  "editDate": "2012-08-29T15:00:00.846Z"
}
```

and I have the index:

```
from doc in docs.Product
select new { doc.editDate }
```

I want to query all documents before a certain date AND time. I can query on the DATE using this syntax:

```
editDate: [NULL TO 2012-09-17]
```

however I can't figure out how to query the time component as well.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query that using:

```
 editDate: [NULL TO 2012-09-17T15:00:00.846Z]
```

If you care for a part of that, use:

```
 editDate: [NULL TO 2012-09-17T15:00]
```

Note that you might have to escape parts of the query, like so:

```
 editDate: [NULL TO 2012\-09\-17T15\:00]
```

For this to work you also need to ensure that the field is analysed.
In Raven Studio - Add Field -> editDate, and set Indexing to Analyzed.

Comment: Yeah it needs to be escaped, however this still did not work for me. If the day is greater (2012-09-18T15:00) then the doc will be found, however if it is the same day but later in the day (2012-09-17T15:30) then the document is not found.

Comment: Figured it out - need to make the field analysed, how do you set this using the http api? (couldn't find it in the docs)

Comment: This is bad advice.  Date fields should never be analyzed.

Answer (score -1):

One way of working around this problem is to store the value not as a date but as the number of seconds since the unix epoch.

This results in a number that you can compare against with ease.

I am using javascript and the moment js library:

```
{
  "editDate": "2012-08-29T15:00:00.846Z",
  "editDateUnix": moment("2012-08-29T15:00:00.846Z").unix()
}
```

Any my index:

```
from doc in docs.Product
select new { doc.editDate, doc.editDateUnix }
```

and my lucene query:

```
"editDate: [NULL TO "+moment("2012-09-17").unix()+"]"
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem or are you looking for further answers?

Comment: It does solve it, however if there is another way to do it then I would love to know what it is!